# Exception using dynamic properties in OData service

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I have defined these classes:

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public List<ReportRow> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class ReportRow
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

And I've configured the site like so;

```
var rowType = builder.ComplexType<ReportRow>();
rowType.HasDynamicProperties(c => c.Values);
var reportType = builder.EntityType<Report>();
reportType.Property(c => c.ID);
reportType.CollectionProperty(c => c.Rows);

builder.EntitySet<Report>("Reports");
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: null,
    model: builder.GetEdmModel()
);
```

But I just get this exception when I call `config.MapODataServiceRoute` above;

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.OData.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Found more than one dynamic property container in type 'ReportRow'. Each open type must have at most one dynamic property container.
```

If I remove the first two lines from WebApiConfig in the above sample, I do not get the same exception.
I followed the sample code on this page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Comment: If you are using `ODataConventionModelBuilder`, then you don't need to manually configure `ReportRow` or `Report`. The model builder will make all of the necessary inferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write code to build model like this
"            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet("Reports");"
It will auto add the referred complex type "ReportRow" and mark it as open type automatically.

If you want to continue to use ODataModelBuilder like the example do, then you need to add reportType.HasKey(c => c.ID); and remove reportType.Property(c => c.ID); as you define an entity type, it must have a key defined.

You can refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#02-01-model-builder-abstract on how to use different model builder to build the model.